# Get URL from Query Parameter

Tags: c#, url

**SAMPLE DATA URL**

```
_http://abc.com/cache.ashx?feedURL=http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=from%3AAbbottNews&rpp=3&clientsource=TWITTERINC_WIDGET&include_entities=true&result_type=recent&1334673762143=cachebust
```

I'm try to get value of query parameter `FeedURL` and below what I get;

**Actual:** `http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=from%3AAbbottNews&rpp=3&clientsource=TWITTERINC_WIDGET&include_entities=true&result_type=recent&1334673762143=cachebust`

**What I'm getting:** `http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=from%3AAbbottNews`

**Required** : I need the complete URL.

**Note:** It truncates from second parameter onwards

**Dirty Solution:**
I tried all suggestions, but I felt there is no better solution. There is no other go, I did a dirty solution to get the right part of the URL completely.

```
/// <summary>
/// Get Feed URL from raw URL
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rawURL"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetFeedURL(string rawURL)
{
    int index = rawURL.IndexOf("=");
    string _rawURL = rawURL;

    if (index > 0)
        _rawURL = _rawURL.Substring(index).Remove(0, 1);

    return _rawURL;
}
```

Comment: Can you post any code as to what you are actually doing?  Your example is very confusing.

Comment: Improved Content with actual sample.

Comment: you either have to encode the path (the ? and the &s cause the parameter to be split) or to concatenate them again

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this may be due to the fact that the first "&" character in your FeedUrl may be getting treated as a query parameter for the outside query string.  You may need to encode the FeedUrl first.  This is just my initial gut feeling.

Answer (score 1):

You need to URLEncode your URL Variables when adding them to the URL...

```
url = "http://url.com?id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("...");
Response.Redirect(url);
```

.. and URLDecode them to work with them after the request...

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

Otherwise the QueryString request doesn't know how to handle all the extra ?'s and &'s.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you provide, while valid, is not going to parse the way you expect; it'll be parsed the way it currently is. Nested query strings are not supported unless the ampersands are encoded.